# Jquery Get data is not returning on redirected page?

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Jquery Get data is sending through anchor tag by click event. It returns data to anchor tag page correctly but when page is redirected it does not returns data to that page. 

There is the anchor tag code. It is dynamically generated. After clicking this anchor tag jquery sends get data to *LikeMail.php* page. which then returns to redirected page (viewProfile.php) through ajax method

```
 <a class="profile" href="<?php echo "viewProfile.php?id=" . $record['user_id'];?>" >
                    <img class="img-rounded"
                         src=" <?php echo "../shadi/images/" . $record['user_photo1'] ?>"
                         id="<?php echo $record['user_id']; ?>"alt="" width="70%" height="20%">

                </a>
```

**This is Jquery method by which data is sending by Get method**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('.profile').on('click', function (e) {

    //Get the href Link
    var href = $(this).attr('href');

    e.preventDefault();
    $.get("LikeMail.php",
        {user2: $(this).find(".img-rounded").attr("id")}, function (returnedData) {

            // Do whatever you want with returend data
            console.log(returnedData);

        }).done(function() {
        window.location.href = href;
    });
    });

});
```

**This is ajax function which receives data in redirected page**

```
function like()
{
    var req  = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function()

    {
        if(req.readyState==4 && req.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById('Like').innerHTML=req.responseText;

        }
    }
    req.open('GET','LikeMail.php','true');
    req.send();
}
setInterval(function(){like()},1000);
```

I want to know that why my jquery Get data returns to anchor tag page BUT why not on redirected page. I want to make it work on redirected page

Comment: with `window.location.href = href;` you're refreshing the page and thus the GET data you're looking for is no longer there/available.

Comment: Then how to send data by anchor tag?

Comment: I have also used `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: To answer your question, i'd need more info, Zain... Why are you redirecting the user after doing a GET request? It looks like you're doing the same GET request on two different pages.. Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Maybe there is a better way to go about what you're trying to do.

Comment: I want to redirect because functioning is to be done on other page

Answer (score 0):

Your data will not exist on the next page after redirect. You can save the data to the session, which will then make it available on the other page.

In your PHP script which receives the data on the first page, save the data you want to keep to the session. [Here is a tutorial about sessions](https://www.sitepoint.com/php-sessions/) if you don't know how to do that.

Now on the other page all you need to do is read the session data which was saved. Looks like you could probably do that just on load of the page, using PHP.

If you want to initiate another ajax call to get the session data (I'm not sure why you want to do that, it doesn't seem like a good solution to anything I can think of) you need to make your ajax request to a PHP script which will return the `$_SESSION` array you set in the previous page.

Comment: Yes I know this solution but the main problem is that sessions are unique throughout the script. If user opens other tab then it generates the problem

Comment: @ZainFarooq Sessions exist beyond the current request. That is the whole point. The session should still be there even in a new tab. If not, it's a problem with the way you are creating sessions or your server configuration.

Comment: @ZainFarooq Anyway, if you want the data to still be there after you redirect, the only way is to store the data somewhere - usually the session or a database.

Comment: You didn't get my point. If some session is set like `$_SESSION['user2']=1` then it will be set throughout the script. Then if user changes `$_SESSION['user2']=2` then previous session will be lost. If user opens two tabs with different `user2` then only latest session will be there

Comment: @ZainFarooq Yes, in that case you must use the database. It sounds like it is the right solution for what you are trying to do.